# Different ways to solve nested radicals with cubic roots

Tags: radicals, cubics

I want to obtain the result of:
$$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{5}+2}-\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{5}-2}$$
Which turns out to be 1. Now, let's prettend we don't know what the result is. I solved it by stating 
$$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{5}+2}-\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{5}-2}=z$$
Then by cubing the equation: 
$$4-3\biggr(\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{5}+2}-\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{5}-2} \biggr)=z^3$$
$$ z^3+3z-4=0$$
Now, just by an inexplicable mysticism, the equation can be restated as: 
$$(z-1)(z^2+z+4)=0$$
Therefore, $z=1$, which is what I wanted to prove.

Are there another ways to solve this problem? I find this method quite impractical and not so elegant. I'm interested in ways to solve it that are MUCH simpler.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you have $z=a-b$ with $a^3-b^3=4, ab=1$, so $z^3$ $=(a-b)^3$ $= a^3-b^3-3ab(a-b)$ $=4 - 3z$. I don't think it gets much simpler than that.

Comment: I think this method is quite good.

Comment: I mean, it is simple because I knew the result was 1, and that makes the factorization simpler. But what if I didn't know? What if the result is actually an irrational number?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to observe that
$$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{5}\pm 2}= \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}\pm 1)$$